# Android Wear "New Bar" for Yes or No Confirmation dialog (Version 5.1)

Tags: wear-os

The android notification which asks for a Yes or No confirmation (as image below) on android wear was created by a custom notification.

[image]

The new version of android wear (5.1) the screen for confirmation is different, like image below. 
[image]

The buttons are in a kind of bar, where this bar goes down after a while (image below)
[image]

And when this bar goes down, you can scroll up (image below) and down (image above)
[image]

Is there a new widget or something to do this new screen with this "new bar"?